# Kendo Grid C# - Select current page without refresh datasource again

Tags: javascript, c#, linq, kendo-ui, grid

i have been trying to fix this, what i want to do is:

I have a datasource who gets data from server, when i go to server, i get the list of items, then i have to search the item i have to select (This item could be in any page), after i have the item and the page where the item is located (assuming each page has 30 items), then i call LINQ expression to skip the required ammount of data and take 30. Finally i return this list to the client side.

When data arrives to client i need to "auto-select" the selected item and change the page to locate the user in the right page where the selected item is located. I have the new page, skip, selected value and everything in the client side again.

What do you suggest to me to change the page into the kendo grid datasource without call a new refresh and go to the server again?

This is how the datasource looks like:

```
return new kendo.data.DataSource({
        serverPaging: true,
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: URLController.Current().getURL('MyURL'),
                contentType: 'application/json',
                accepts: 'application/json',
                type: 'POST'
            },
            parameterMap: function(data, type) {
                if (data) {
                    return JSON.stringify(
                    {
                        data: jsonData,
                        pageSize: data.pageSize,
                        skip: data.skip,
                        take: data.take
                    });
                }
            }
        },
        schema: {
            data: function (data) {
                var dropDownData = JSON.parse(data);
                gridElement.attr('data-model', JSON.stringify({ data: data }));

                return dropDownData.Data;
            },
            total: function (data) {
                var dropDownData = JSON.parse(data);
                return dropDownData.total;
            },
            model: {
                id: 'ID'
            }
        },
        pageable: true,
        pageSize: 30,
        error: function(e) {
            alert('Error ' + e);
        }
    });
```

When the grid data is bounded i have to change the page to current page number and then select the current item.

```
grid.one('dataBound', function (e) {
            var currentGridElement = this.element;
            var currentModel = currentGridElement.attr('data-model');
            var currentJsonData = parseDropDownDataJSONString(currentModel).data;
            var gridDataSource = this.dataSource;
            var selection = gridDataSource.get(currentJsonData.selectedValue);
            if (selection != undefined) {
                var row = currentGridElement.find('tbody>tr[data-uid=' + selection.uid + ']');
                if (row != undefined) {
                    currentGridElement.attr('data-closeByChange', false);
                    gridDataSource.page(currentJsonData.pageNumber);
                    this.select(row);
                    dexonDropDownGrid.combobox().text(selection.DISPLAY);
                }
            }
            var aaaa = 0;
        });
```

This is how my databound event listener looks like, when i try to set the page it calls again the server and i got more delay to load the right data.

Is there any way to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have the same problem.

There is how I fix that(not the best solution ever, but it works):

```
var forcedPageChange = false;
var cachedResult;

var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: function (options) {
            if (forcedPageChange) { // prevent data request after manual page change
                forcedPageChange = false;
                options.success(cachedResult);
                cachedResult = null;
                return;
            }

            gridDataProvider.getData() // promise of data
                    .then(function (result) {
                        // check if current page number was changed
                        if ($scope.gridConfig.dataSource.page() !== result.pageNumber ||
                                $scope.gridConfig.dataSource.pageSize() !== result.rowsPerPage) {
                            cachedResult = _.clone(result);
                            forcedPageChange = true;
                            options.page = result.pageNumber;
                            options.pageSize = result.rowsPerPage;
                            $scope.gridConfig.dataSource.query(options);
                        }

                        options.success(result);
                    }, function () {
                        options.error();
                    });
        }
    },
    schema: {
        data: function (response) {
            return response.items;
        },
        total: function (response) {
            return response.totalCount;
        }
    },
    //...
    serverPaging: true,
    serverSorting: true,
    serverFiltering: true
});
```

I found that `dataSource.page(newPageNumber)` doesn't work in this situation. It just drop page number to 1.

This solution works, but I still have a bug with missing sorting icon after `dataSource.query(options)`...